# Map database object to source implementation

Tags: database, oop, object, architecture

What would be the best way to tie a database object to a source code implementation? Basically so that I could have a table of "ingredients" that could be referred to by objects from another table containing a "recipe", while still being able to index and search efficiently by their metadata. Also taking into account that some "ingredients" might inherit from other "ingredients".

Maybe I'm looking at this in a totally wrong way, would appreciate any light on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've correctly understood your goal, there should be these two choices:

- Use an [OR/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and don't try to implement the data mapping yourself from scratch.
- Switch to a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) storage. Analyze your data model and see if it's not very relational and it can be expressed using a document storage like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/). For example, MongoDB already supports [indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/).